# How can I convert simple product to bundle product programmatically

Tags: magento-enterprise, simple-product, bundle-product, product-type

I have a system which has a set of products of three "types":

1. Simple products without associated products;
2. Group products;
3. Simple products, which are associated to group products.

I need to:

- convert type 1 into bundle product and create associated simple product.
- convert type 2 into bundle product and keep it's associated simple products.

I know already about this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/displaze-change-product-type.html but seems be capable of only converting `simple -> bundle`, while I also need `grouped -> bundle` conversion.

**UPDATE 2:**
Since it is not possible to change product types with `avs-fastsimpleimport`, I removed anything about it from the question.

**UPDATE 1:** 
Based on this questions and answers I made up my solution: [1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5952/how-to-programmatically-create-a-bundled-product), [2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8228/what-table-links-a-simple-product-to-a-configurable-product), [3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/query-to-get-all-simple-products-which-are-not-part-of-a-complex-product), [4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14518/convert-configurable-product-to-bundle-product).
Here is the MySQL update code, which actually does the trick for me:

```
/*
 * preparing list of simple products,
 * which are not associated with any other
 * complex products (group, bundle, configurable and so on)
 */
SET @simpleSkuList = (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(sku)
    FROM
        catalog_product_entity
    WHERE
        type_id = 'simple'
        AND LENGTH(sku) = 8
        AND(
            entity_id NOT IN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    (product_id)
                FROM
                    catalog_product_super_link /* associated product ids of configurable */
                UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        (linked_product_id)
                    FROM
                        catalog_product_link /* associated product ids of grouped */
                UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        (child_id)
                    FROM
                        catalog_product_relation /* associated product ids of bundled and grouped */
            )
        )
    GROUP BY type_id
);

/* changing simple products type to be 'bundle' products */
UPDATE
    catalog_product_entity
SET
    type_id = 'bundle'
WHERE find_in_set(sku, @simpleSkuList);
```

And the question now sound like, does anybody think that this MySQL query can be improved somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like my solution haven't caused much issues on our system so far.

So, this MySQL code does actual trick:

```
/*
 * preparing list of simple products,
 * which are not associated with any other
 * complex products (group, bundle, configurable and so on)
 */
SET @simpleSkuList = (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(sku)
    FROM
        catalog_product_entity
    WHERE
        type_id = 'simple'
        AND LENGTH(sku) = 8 /* our criteria to identify products, which need update */
        AND(
            entity_id NOT IN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    (product_id)
                FROM
                    catalog_product_super_link /* associated product ids of configurable */
                UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        (linked_product_id)
                    FROM
                        catalog_product_link /* associated product ids of grouped */
                UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        (child_id)
                    FROM
                        catalog_product_relation /* associated product ids of bundled and grouped */
            )
        )
    GROUP BY type_id
);

/* changing simple products type to be 'bundle' products */
UPDATE
    catalog_product_entity
SET
    type_id = 'bundle'
WHERE find_in_set(sku, @simpleSkuList);
```

We also doing the same for group products, but at the same time removing all custom options from group product itself. As well as removing all child-to-parent relations.
We don't care about these relations - they will be re-created on import. But we have to keep products, since they have media files attached, which is not part of the import.